# Can I null-check in-line?

Tags: java, null, nullpointerexception

I have a Java command that looks something like below:

```
Foo f = new Foo();
String string = f.format(new Bar().getSelection());
                       // ^ may be null
```

Sometimes it's possible that my `Bar` object returns null, this is by design.

To me, the natural thing to do is to split the commands into multiple lines and do a null-check separately, such as:

```
Foo f = new Foo();
BarSel bs = new Bar().getSelection();
String string = "";
if (bs != null) {
    string = f.format(bs);
    // continue...
}
```

However, I'm wondering if there is a way to do this in one line? Is it possible to null-check objects inline?

*I seem to remember reading about being able to use question mark, but I can't recall the exact syntax and I might be wrong about that. Note that I'm not referring to the ternary operator, although that is another valid approach.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you remember the elvis operator ( http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-March/000047.html ) which was rejected ( https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/project_coin_final_five ) from project coin.

However, the jakarta commons have nvl-like functions such as http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#defaultString(java.lang.String)  Even though these functions are not standard java, they end up in most programs as dependecy of some library.

The problem you have is a common when you design a function with a valid null result: You have to document and handle the special case everywhere.  I can pretty much guarantee you that someone will mess this up in maintenance, resulting in spurious null pointer exceptions. That's why i would, in general, recommend designs that don't return null.

Comment: This is exactly what I was referring to actually.

Answer (score 14):

With the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a#Java) :

```
String string = bs != null ? f.format(bs) : "";
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that, while I'm aware of the ternary operator, I'd have liked to avoid it for once

Answer (score 8):

I'm late to the game but I wanted something similar and found use of Java 8 [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) class. Solution for problem statement in question:

```java
String string = Optional.ofNullable(bs).map(f::format).orElse("");
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way with the **ternary operator**:

```
String string = bs == null ? "" : f.format(bs);
```

Answer (score 1):

not in java,  but some JVM based languages ( notable: groovy )   have null safe dereference:

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Null+Object+Pattern

Comment: It is also possible to implement it in java.

Comment: It is possible ti implement with JVM but not in java.  Though you can intermix groovy and java - groovy compiles itself to java classes and is executed on jvm. ( being able to use nice syntax sugar and  goodies like closures lead to development of alternative JVM languages)

Comment: I meant, the Null Object pattern can be implemented in java, not the null safe dereference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ternary operator.

`string = bs != null ? f.format(bs) : "";`

This would give you an empty string literal if bs is not null. Or you could just use:

`if (bs != null) string = f.format(bs);`

Answer (score 0):

```
Foo f = new Foo();
BarSel bs = new Bar().getSelection();
String string = bs != null ? f.format(bs) : "";
```